# Sequelize / Vue / Node - I'd like to use a query to filter data after it has been returned to my view

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, sequelize.js

I have a table that tracks all user responses to a quiz. This query will successfully get all the data from that table and put it into my TotalQuizResponses array which I then use in my view:

```js
this.totalQuizResponses = ((await QuizResponsesService.index()).data)
```

However, I'd also like to display the total number of matches in my view. I know this SQL query successfully gets that total number of matches from the table data:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM QuizResponses A, QuizResponses B
WHERE A.answerKey = B.answerKey AND A.QuizId = B.QuizId AND A.UserId < B.UserId
```

I don't want to have to do another service call just to get the count on filtered data that I already have inside my view. Is there a way to somehow filter the data from within the view? I'm unsure how to replicate this logic using pure JavaScript. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the exact same query on unfiltered data:

```js
countResponses(this.totalQuizResponses);

function countResponses(quizData) {
  let counter = 0;

  for (const quizResponseA of quizData) {
    for (const quizResponseB of quizData) {
      if (quizResponseA === quizResponseB) { continue; }

      const isSameAnswerKey = quizResponseA.answerKey === quicResponseB.answerKey;
      const isSameQuizId = quizResponseA.QuizId === quizResponseB.QuizId;
      const isSameUser = quizResponseA.UserId === quizResponseB.UserId;

      if (isSameAnswerKey && isSameQuizzId && isSameUser) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }

  return counter;
}
```

**If you already filtered your data with the same query**, `this.totalQuizResponses.length` is the same as a counter for all the data you have locally